# Async or Defer Jssor Dependencies

Tags: javascript, jssor

I have a very basic Jssor Slider implementation, which I've uploaded here:
http://preview.sparkplugengine.com/JssorDev/

I'd like to load the dependencies with ASYNC or DEFER, but I'm struggling with figuring out how to do that and have the slider execute. I don't have a ton of experience with JavaScript or programming asynchronously (obviously).

Has anyone solved this with JSSOR or know of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onload` attribute in the script tag to execute code once the script has loaded.

- With a single dependency, you can use that to run code straight away.
- With multiple dependencies, you need to count those `load` events and run code when all dependencies have loaded.

In both cases, you need to wrap your existing code in a function and preferably define it before loading your dependencies.

### Multiple dependencies example

```
<script>
    var ready = 0; // defined in global scope

    function doStuff() {
        // don't run until we have loaded 2 dependencies
        if(++ready < 2) {
            return;
        }
        // run
        console.log('loaded 2 dependencies, now doing stuff');
    }
</script>
<script async defer src="dep1.js" onload="doStuff()"></script>
<script async defer src="dep2.js" onload="doStuff()"></script>
```